# Sacar un valor (que es una fecha) de un dataframe en función del valor de una columna

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Tengo un dataFrame leido con python pandas que es de la siguiente manera:

```
index    fecha     cant_A  cant_B  cant_C
Felix   24/01/2020    48     40      50
Manolo  25/01/2020     0     100     96
Luis    26/01/2020     1     10      12
Pedro   27/01/2020     3     2       20
```

Mi duda es qué línea de código deberia de introducir para que al localizar el valor por ejemplo de 100 en la columna cant_B, me devuelva el valor que tiene en la columna fecha. Es decir, el valor 100 ya lo tengo localizado y guardado (sólo el valor), y quiero que me escriba el valor de la celda de la columna fecha que corresponde a la fila que tiene ese valor 100. Me tendría que escribir: 25/01/2020.

La columna fecha del dataframe me la reconoce como 'object'.

Gracias

Answer (score 1):

Crearé un **dataframe básico de ejemplo**:

```
import pandas as pd

lists = [
            ['Felix', '24/01/2020', 48, 40, 50],
            [ 'Manolo', '25/01/2020', 0, 100, 96]
        ]

df = pd.DataFrame(lists, columns = ['index', 'fecha', 'cant_A', 'cant_B', 'cant_C'])
```

El **contenido de df** es el siguiente:

```
    index       fecha  cant_A  cant_B  cant_C
0   Felix  24/01/2020      48      40      50
1  Manolo  25/01/2020       0     100      96
```

Puedes usar el método `loc` para ubicar las columnas que tengan este valor numérico seteado a 100:

```
print(df.loc[df['cant_B'] == 100])
```

Esto te **imprimirá lo siguiente**:

```
    index       fecha  cant_A  cant_B  cant_C
1  Manolo  25/01/2020       0     100      96
```

Puedes **acceder a esta columna**:

```
print(df.loc[df['cant_B'] == 100]['fecha'])
```

Y obtener el valor de fecha que se encuentra como índice 1:

```
print(df.loc[df['cant_B'] == 100]['fecha'][1])
```

**EDITO**:

Me has comentado que usas de índice la columna de nombres, colocaré un `set_index()` para hacerlo en este caso.

```
import pandas as pd

lists = [
            ['Felix', '24/01/2020', 48, 40, 50],
            [ 'Manolo', '25/01/2020', 0, 100, 96]
        ]

df = pd.DataFrame(lists, columns = ['index', 'fecha', 'cant_A', 'cant_B', 'cant_C'])
df = df.set_index('index')
```

Si **imprimo el contenido del dataframe**, tenemos el siguiente resultado:

```
             fecha  cant_A  cant_B  cant_C
index                                     
Felix   24/01/2020      48      40      50
Manolo  25/01/2020       0     100      96
```

**Ahora podemos acceder** a fecha:

```
print(df.loc[df['cant_B'] == 100]['fecha'])
```

**Nos devuelve**:

```
index
Manolo    25/01/2020
Name: fecha, dtype: object
```

Y **accedemos a su posición**:

```
print(df.loc[df['cant_B'] == 100]['fecha'][0])
```

**Resultado**:

```
25/01/2020
```

Answer (score 0):

Muchas gracias Adrián. Me queda una duda que ha sido error mío al no especificarlo bien.

La columna 'index' que he puesto yo con los nombres de las personas, no es que se llame index, si no que es la columna que he puesto como df.set_index() en python.

Entonces, mi duda final sería... ¿qué parámetro habría que meter en la última línea del código que me has dicho? (lo he sustituido por un asterisco).
Hay que tener en cuenta que a priori ese valor no lo sabría (el '1' que has puesto tu), no sabría en que fila está.

```
   df.loc[df['cant_B'] == 100]['fecha'][*]
```

O igual creo que al no saber ese valor (1 en el caso que has puesto, ya que lo has hecho a mano y lo sabes), ya no se haría de esa manera.

Gracias,
Un saludo

Comment: Hola. Edité pregunta usando un ejemplo con set_index(). Puedes imprimir el contenido del dataframe `print(df)` y ya ves que posición usa para acceder a él. Si aún así no te funciona, podrías añadir el código para construir tu dataframe y nos guiamos de él. Una cosilla, si necesitas comentar alguna respuesta que te den, usa el apartado de comentarios y elimina esta respuesta y si necesitas añadir más información edita tu pregunta. Ya que este apartado es solo para responder tus preguntas. Hacer el recorrido te ayudará [https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour]. Un saludo y espero poder ayudarte.

Comment: Hola Adrián! con esa respuesta del set_index() me ha servido a la perfección! Muchas gracias, lo leeré. Un abrazo

Comment: Hola @Acm. No olvides puntuar y/o marcar la respuesta como válida si te ha servido de ayuda. De esta forma contribuyes con la comunidad [https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/427/c%C3%B3mo-funciona-la-aceptaci%C3%B3n-de-respuestas]. Me alegro que te haya ayudado. Saludos.

Comment: Hecho Adrián. Otra cosa más aprendida!