# Obtener un valor de una columna proveniente del valor de otra columna (buscar en la misma fila pero columna diferente)

Tags: python, pandas, date

Tendo un dataframe con pandas que es de la siguiente manera:

```
index      fecha     A      B
Pedro    23/02/2020  10    20
Manuel   24/02/2020  45    5 
Eva      25/02/2020  4     6
```

Quería saber si por ejemplo, sabiendo el valor de la columna 'A' que es 45, sacar automáticamente el valor que tiene la columna fecha que es 24/02/2020.

Debería ser algo como: ''Cuando en la columna A un valor de cualquier fila sea 45 (valor que se previamente, lo puedo pasar como variable), que me de como resultado el valor de la columna fecha que corresponde a la fila que tiene como valor 45 de la columna A.

Valor a sacar del dataframe por pantalla por ejemplo:

```
24/02/2020
```

Luego, el resultado debería ser metido en una celda de otro dataframe, por ejemplo:

```
A  Fecha
45 24/02/2020
```

No se si puede dar problemas que la columna fecha en python sea de tipo object.

Gracias.

Comment: Hola. Bienvenido a stackoverflow en español. Te he respondido algo parecido en esta pregunta [https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/391386/sacar-un-valor-que-es-una-fecha-de-un-dataframe-en-funci%c3%b3n-del-valor-de-una-co/391449]. Intenta añadir el código con lo que has intentado para que tu pregunta sea bien recibida y te pueda ayudar la comunidad. De lo contrario podría ser votada de forma negativa. Te invito a leer el siguiente apartado de cómo preguntar: [https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask]. Saludos.

Comment: Perdona Adrián, soy nuevo en la comunidad y la verdad es que debería de haber leído como preguntar correctamente con anteriorirdad. También pensaba que se había borrado, por eso la he vuelto a formular.

Te agradezco la ayuda y tu ayuda. En cuanto pueda me pongo al día.

Un saludo

Comment: No te preocupes. Cualquier duda para eso estamos. Espero te resuelva la duda en la otra pregunta. Un saludo.